# jQuery Validate SubmitHandler with Ajax Submission Not being hit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

On my view I want to submit the form to the controller using ajax.  I have this:

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Mask
            $("#Teu_Rate").mask("####.##", { reverse: true });
            $("#Mcsap_Rate").mask("####.##", { reverse: true });

            // Submission
            var redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "tblPersonnels")';
            var settings = {};
            settings.baseUri = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
            var infoGetUrl = "";
            if (settings.baseUri === "/Scalehouse") {
                infoGetUrl = settings.baseUri + "/tblPersonnels/Create/";
            } else {
                infoGetUrl = settings.baseUri + "tblPersonnels/Create/";
            }

            // ajax portion
            $("form").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: infoGetUrl,
                        method: "POST",
                        data: $("form").serialize(),
                        beforeSend: disableCreateBtn(),
                        success: function() {
                            console.log("success");
                            toastr.options = {
                                positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                                onHidden: function() {
                                    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                                },
                                timeOut: 3000
                            }
                            toastr.success("Personnel successfully created")
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            toastr.options = {
                                positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                                onHidden: function() {
                                    enableCreateBtn();
                                },
                                timeOut: 3000
                            }
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
                return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
            }

            function disableCreateBtn() {
                $('#Personnel-Create-Btn').prop('disabled', true);
            }

            function enableCreateBtn() {
                $('#Personnel-Create-Btn').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

When the request is done and completed successfully, I should be getting a message in my console and a toastr notification, but I am receiving neither and I'm not receiving any console errors, but the record that I am entering is being entered successfully, so that means that the form is being submitted through regular MVC conventions.

How do I make my ajax submission work?

**Update**

After commenting below with Sparky, I've changed my code to:

```
$("form").submit(function (t) {

    t.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: infoGetUrl,
            method: "POST",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            beforeSend: disableCreateBtn(),
            success: function() {
                console.log("success");
                toastr.options = {
                    positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                    onHidden: function() {
                        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                    },
                    timeOut: 3000
                }
                toastr.success("Personnel successfully created");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                toastr.options = {
                    positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                    onHidden: function() {
                        enableCreateBtn();
                    },
                    timeOut: 3000
                }
                var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                //var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });

    });
```

Now, if the form is empty.. and I hit the create button.. somehow the ajax is going into the success function while giving me my validation errors on certain fields that are required.. then redirected to another page as if the request was successful.. any ideas?

**Update 2**

I got it working by using this syntax:

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler =
    function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: infoGetUrl,
            method: "POST",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            beforeSend: disableCreateBtn(),
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");
                toastr.options = {
                    positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                    onHidden: function () {
                        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                    },
                    timeOut: 3000
                }
                toastr.success("Personnel successfully created.");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                toastr.options = {
                    positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
                    onHidden: function () {
                        enableCreateBtn();
                    },
                    timeOut: 3000
                }
                var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(error);

                var modelState = error.modelState;
                //console.log(modelState);
                $.each(modelState,
                    function (key, value) {
                        var id = "";
                        if (key === "$id") {
                            id = "#" + key.replace('$', '').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + key.substr(2);
                        } else {
                            //console.log(key);
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            toastr.error(status + " - " + modelState[key]);
                        }
                        var input = $(id);
                        //console.log(id); // result is #id
                        if (input) { // if element exists
                            console.log(id);
                            input.addClass('input-validation-error');
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know why, but it is working.. I'm interested in hearing why though

Comment: Are you using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin built into ASP?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure, but in my bundle.config I am not referencing any scripts with the name `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.  The only thing I am referencing in my view is: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Comment: @Sparky in my source code when I inspect an element it does have the `data-val-required` attributes which is unobtrusive based on my research?

Comment: @Sparky I apologize, in my Bundle config I have `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));` which would include the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` because of the `*`.. so yes I am using unobtrusive

Comment: Unobtrusive automatically constructs the `.validate()` method.  Since you are only allowed to call `.validate()` one time, your call to `.validate()` would be ignored when Unobtrusive is being used.

Comment: @Sparky so now, I've switched to just using `$.submit(function(x)..` and now if the entire form is empty and I hit the create button.. I get the validation along with the toastr notification and then I'm redirected to the `redirectUrl` as if it went through successfully.. well it had to have hit the `success` function in order to get that response.. any ideas?

Comment: @Sparky updated my question

Comment: @Sparky I got it working and updated my question as to how.. but could you explain why this syntax works over the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got it working and updated my question as to how.. but could you explain why this syntax works over the others?

Your `.submit()` handler is a bad idea because it's going to interfere with the way the jQuery Validate plugin handles the form's submit event.  (Basically, you've prevented the default submit and then never turned it back over to the Validate plugin.)  ASP or not, this is absolutely not the way to do it.  The Validate plugin provides the `submitHandler` function for any purpose where you need to capture this event.

Your `.settings.submitHandler` works because it's the only way to define the `submitHandler` function when you have no access to write your own `.validate()` method (thanks to Unobtrusive Validation plugin).  [As per the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), the `submitHandler` is the *"right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"*.

---

> so if I were not to use the unobtrusive, then I could use my original code?

The jQuery Validate plugin is initialized via the `.validate()` method, normally on page load.  This method can only be called one time and all subsequent calls will be ignored.  When you use ASP and the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, it constructs and calls the `.validate()` method for you, therefore you can no longer set any options or rules by calling `.validate()` yourself.

Comment: Okay, so if I were not to use the unobtrusive, then I could use my original code?  So, as of now, what I have is correct?

Comment: @M12Bennett, basically yes, assuming your original code didn't leave out any options you want.  Without the Unobtrusive plugin, you would write your own `.validate()` method with whatever rules and options you wish.  Otherwise, Unobtrusive does it for you... hence the terminology:  "unobtrusive"