# Validation does not work when using AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to validate fields with `ValidationMessageFor`, and everything works fine if you submit the form using `Html.Beginform`, but if I use an AJAX query, then validations no longer work.
My Code
View:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Client

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .form-signin {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .input-group-text {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
</style>

@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CName, "Имя")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите имя" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "Отчество")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CPatronymic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPatr", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите отчество" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Login, "Логин")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtLogin", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите логин" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Password, "Пароль")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(i => i.Password, new { @id = "txtPass", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите пароль" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Email, "E-Mail")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите e-mail", @type = "email" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Добавить" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Authorization/Registration",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $(location).attr('href', result.URL);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(Client client)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /*unitOfWork.Clients.Create(client);
                unitOfWork.Save();*/
                var url = new { URL = Url.Content("/Authorization/Index") + "#success" };
                return Json(url);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

_Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

With this option validation works, but only after the form is submitted. And after performing the Ajax request, it does not redirect me to the address that I collect in the controller, but instead simply displays this address as a string on the screen. And if instead of using jquery `Ajax.Beginform`, then, validation does not work when the form has already been submitted, but immediately after entering incorrect data in the input field.
[image]

Comment: You need to use `jQuery.validate` library as provided in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005773/use-asp-net-mvc-validation-with-jquery-ajax) and set validation rules depending on requirements.

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208543/594235

Comment: @Sparky, i try it's, but not work. I give an example of my code at the end of the question.

Comment: @Sparky It turned out to make so that validation would work immediately when entering data into text fields. Forgot to add first `$(document).ready`, but there was another problem. After performing the Ajax request, the program does not transfer to the page with the address I return to the controller, but simply writes this address as a string on the screen. The screenshot at the end of the question.

Comment: @Sparky And what is most interesting, in the debugging of the client, the code does not even enter the block of the succession. Then I decided to check on the server `Request.IsAjaxRequest` and result 'false'. Why the server does not consider my request, Ajax request. And how to fix it? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.  If you want to transfer to a new page after submit, then Ajax is pointless.  Standard form submission redirects/reloads.  Ajax does not redirect/reload, which is the whole point of Ajax... to do data transmission to server without redirecting or reloading the page.

Comment: @Sparky, yes, but I need, depending on the result of the execution, to return the desired action, therefore, I use Ajax.

Comment: @Sparky and if i will use `Ajax.Beginform` Everything will work to the end as it should, and for your option, the server for some reason does not consider the request, the Ajax as a request, and therefore after trying to redirect to another page, this does not work.

Comment: @Sparky Why doesn't the success function work in your version of the query?

Comment: @Sparky, I understood what was going on, I did not send an ajax request, but a normal request. How to make it so that the Ajax request is sent?

Comment: @Sparky, maybe it's because I haven't written `return false`? But I tried it with him, and still it is not the Ajax request that is sent.