# jquery .valid() not working when resending the same form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I think this it's simple but I can't figure it out,

I have a form a simple one that asks for a name, date one and date two.

when you submit here's the jquery

```
    $('#searchRange').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var x = $(this).serialize();
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/Statistics/Home',
              data: x,
              cache: false,
              beforeSend: function () {
                  $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
              },
              success: function (e) {
                  $('#sellsTable').html(e);
              },
              complete: function () {
                  $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeOut();
              }
           });
        }
    })
```

the ajax return a table that is inserted into a div, until this point it's fine.

but now when I modify the form chaging some values and I click the submit button to resend the form, this is what I get from the console:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function**

does anyone know why? and how can I fix it?

thanks.

**UPDATED**

Here is the bundleconfig file:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom-validators").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/custom-validators.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myScripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Plugin.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Velocity.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Chart.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Admin.js"));
```

and here's the form:

```
<form id="searchRange">
<label class="col-sm-auto text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            Nombre:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm text-center mr-3" })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger", type = "date" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-auto text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            Fecha desde:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateFrom, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm text-center mr-3" })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateFrom, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger", type = "date" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-auto text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            Fecha hasta:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateUntil, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm text-center mr-3" })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateUntil, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger", type = "date" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Buscar" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

UPDATED

here's how I changed the submit

```
     $('#searchPositionsByCode').validate({
        submitHandeler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $(form).attr("method"),
                url: $(form).attr("action"),
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
                },
                success: function (e) {
                    $('#infoByCodeDisplayed').html(e);
                    $('#infoByCodeDisplayed').removeClass('d-none');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeOut();
                }
            })
        return false; 
        }
    });
```

but this way use the default submit jquery validation, it doesn't execute the ajax, and redirects me to the other page.

any ideas?

Comment: Could you please show us your form.

Comment: You are doing in the wrong way

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda how so?

Comment: The `.valid()` method can only be called ***after*** the `.validate()` method.  The `.validate()` method is automatically created by the Unobtrusive Validation plugin as part of ASP.  You have to inspect your DOM to make sure your timing is correct.  When using jQuery Validate plugin, the click event of the submit button is captured automatically, so there is absolutely no reason for you to have created a `submit` event handler function.

Comment: @Sparky I changed he way I control the submit but it is still not working

Comment: IF you are using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin as part of ASP, then your call to `.validate()` is **going to be ignored**.  The `.validate()` method can only be called ONE time and Unobtrusive Validation will take priority.

Comment: @Sparky any way to do it with unobtrusive? or my only way is doing it without it?

Comment: Since you left unobtrusive out of your OP, you turned this into a real guessing game.  Yes, you can search other posts here on SO, but basically you have to use the `.setDefaults()` method to pass the `submitHandler` option.

Comment: @Sparky Since you left unobtrusive out of your OP how so?

Comment: You mention "Unobtrusive Validation" exactly zero times in your OP, don't even show it bundled, or tag it.  Since you're using a framework that has exclusive control over the plugin you're asking about when using its internal validation, it's kinda important to mention that little configuration detail.  Your situation is completely different than somebody simply adding the jQuery Validate plugin to their website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED IT **

a better way was recommended by @Sparky and by doing so it still works

```
    $('#searchRange').data('validator').settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Statistics/Home',
            data: $('#searchRange').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
            },
            success: function (e) {
                $('#sellsTable').html(e);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.dk-linear-loading-wrapper').fadeOut();
            }
        })
```

Comment: Using an external `submit` handler with this plugin is not a great solution.  [There are better ways shown in similar questions posted on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208543/594235).

Answer (score -1):

You need to require the jQuery valid plugin below jQuery for it to work

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

You can also checkout [jQuery validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)